# I can not fix the view(Ionic2)

Tags: html, css, ionic2

My title changes according to data coming.But header lengths are different and appearance changes.I need to fix the view.Where did I go wrong?what should I do

[image]

[image]

[image]

**home.html**

```
  <ion-row>
   <ion-col col-7>
      <div class="headerline"></div>
   </ion-col>
 </ion-row>
 <ion-row>
   <ion-col>
     <div class="header">
     <h3 >{{header}}</h3>
     </div>
   </ion-col>
 </ion-row>
```

**home.scss**

```
   .header{
    color:white;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: -57px;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    clear:both;
  }

  .header h3{
   font-size: 20px;
  }

 .headerline{
    width: 50px;
    height: 47px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ef3a4f;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block; 
    position: relative;
    top: -18px;
  }
```

Comment: How do you expect it to show?

Comment: Like the first image (organization)

Comment: Not really clear where your problem is? Do you want the title to have a fixed left padding or you want your title to be centered?

Comment: These titles are in the middle of the screen.But as the writing length increases, the view is not what I want.I want the titles to be right in the middle of the screen and look like the first picture